# Postgresql unicode LOWER()

Tags: postgresql, unicode, ascii

The following query:

```
select lower('ALGODÓN'), upper('algodón')
```

Results in:

```
  lower  |  upper
---------+---------
 algodÓn | ALGODóN
(1 row)
```

Python, on the other hand, gets this right:

```
>>> 'ALGODÓN'.lower()
'algodón'
```

Is there a way to get postgres to convert case of non-ascii characters properly?

Comment: What's the collation of the column?

Comment: There's no column, the query above works as shown on a default install of postgres 13.5

Comment: Then, you'll probably need to enforce a collation since the default collation is not what you need. From the manual "... If the expression is a constant, the collation is the default collation of the data type of the constant..." at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/collation.html

Comment: The world doesn't agree on how to sort and change cases, though there are ways to do it which will be more correct more often, so we need [collations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) and [locales](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/locale.html).

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong collation.  For example, with the `C` collation:

```
SELECT lower('ALGODÓN' COLLATE "C"), upper('algodón' COLLATE "C");

  lower  │  upper  
═════════╪═════════
 algodÓn │ ALGODóN
(1 row)
```

But with `en_US.utf8` (Linux):

```
SELECT lower('ALGODÓN' COLLATE "en_US.utf8"), upper('algodón' COLLATE "en_US.utf8");

  lower  │  upper  
═════════╪═════════
 algodón │ ALGODÓN
(1 row)
```

The language-agnostic ICU collation gets it right too:

```
SELECT lower('ALGODÓN' COLLATE "und-x-icu"), upper('algodón' COLLATE "und-x-icu");

  lower  │  upper  
═════════╪═════════
 algodón │ ALGODÓN
(1 row)
```